# High efficiency gas furnace part name

Tags: furnace

I'm looking for the name of the plastic piece that is labeled #2 in the attached picture.

The condensate goes into the plastic box and then overflows into a tube that goes to the sump.

I'm having the hardest time finding the name of the piece.

[image]

Comment: What is the model number for your furnace? That part is a specialty part for your furnace, not a common everyday part. Get with the manufacturer for the information.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Does the furnace have name? make and model? have you looked in the manual, have you searched the intertubes for a manual/parts list? Why do you need to know its name.  (What isherwood said).  **Guess based on info provided**. - *Condensate pump cover for X brand/model of High efficiency furnace**.

Answer (score 2):

To me your parts names are:

1. condensate pump
2. condensate drain assembly
3. discharge hose for condensate pump

The drain assembly is different than the ones I have used and in some cases I don’t use OEM parts because of the cost when a standard off the shelf part can be made or purchased for much less.

Comment: Thank you.  This is not my furnace, just a picture from the internet that actually showed the part I was looking for.  I eventually did end up finding it:

https://www.ferguson.com/product/goodman-plastic-drain-trap-g20171701/_/R-2303756

Answer (score 1):

It is a condensate drain trap.